# Can X ray spectroscopy determine if a photon has left the lens of a camera?

Tags: photons

I'm interested in knowing if you could measure a photon and see if it has left a material like silicon, which both the lens and CMOS sensor would contain. This wouldn't work if any nearby buildings had glass windows, so maybe only as a sensor for a plane or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to know if the photon has passed through a lens, without detecting the photon.  At the moment a photon is detected, it ceases to be a photon.